# All VHOSTS use the first configured SSL certificate

Tags: apache2

I have a server with two VHOSTS. When I started serving websites on this server I only had one VHOST and I did not have any experience with configuring VHOSTS, so I might have edited configuration files in a directory other than `sites-available`. At some point I enabled SSL for my first domain using Let's Encrypt. Lets call it `firstdomain.com`, SSL works perfectly fine here.

I then started adding other domains, `seconddomain.com`. This second domain works well on HTTP however when browsed to on HTTPS it serves the SSL certificate of `firstdomain.com` and thus shows an browser warning that the SSL certificate is invalid. However the configuration seems to be correct.

I also made a few edits to the `000-default-le-ssl.conf` and I think that they may have caused the issue however I am unsure about what settings I can remove or edit without Apache dying. So far whenever I delete parts of the `000-default-le-ssl.conf` Apache fails to reload.

**000-default-le-ssl.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/firstdomain.com


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/firstdomain.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/firstdomain.com/privkey.pem

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

    ServerName firstdomain.com

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
</IfModule>
```

**firstdomain.com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@firstdomain.com
    ServerName firstdomain.com
    ServerAlias www.firstdomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/firstdomain.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**firstdomain.conf-ssl.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/firstdomain.com

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/firstdomain.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/firstdomain.com/privkey.pem

        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

        ServerName firstdomain.com

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
</IfModule>
```

**seconddomain.com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@seconddomain.com
    ServerName seconddomain.com
    ServerAlias www.seconddomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/seconddomain.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**seconddomain.com-ssl.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/seconddomain.com

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/seconddomain.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/seconddomain.com/privkey.pem

        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

        ServerName seconddomain.com

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Two configuration snippets for the same ServerName is redundant, lose either 000-default-le-ssl.conf or  firstdomain.conf-ssl.conf. Second, depending on the Linux distribution you use,  configuration file snippets need to be in the correct locations to be loaded by `Include` or `IncludeOptional` directives in the main httpd.conf  and a new file in for instance a "sites-available" subdirectory needs a symbolic link from the "sites-enabled" subdirectory before a web server restart will include it.   `a2ensite` may be used to manage such symbolic links.

Comment: @HBruijn When I attempt to delete the 000-default-le-ssl.conf apache2 does not restart anymore. The site configurations listed are enabled with a2ensite but SSL still does not work properly on the second domain.